# Vibration motion at the imaginary frequency for TS of the Claisen rearrangment

Tags: computational-chemistry

I understand that the vibration along the reaction coordinate is different for the transition state , as the motion of the atoms takes TS towards products/reactants.

However, what would be the vibrational motion corresponding to the imaginary frequency of the Claisen rearrangement?

[image: Claisen rearrangment]

Answer (score 4):

I started at PM7 niveau, where it looks like this:

[image: G16 Rev A03, PM7 TS]

and at the DFT niveau (DF-B97-D3/def2-SV(P)) it is not that different:

[image: G16 Rev A03, B97D3/def2SV/W06 TS]

To summarize: Id say, it looks "as expected".

The transition state needs to connect both local minima. When you follow the animation of the normal modes above, you can see bond forming and bond breaking between either the two carbons on the left top or the carbon and the oxygen on the bottom right.

---

```
#p pm7 opt=(ts,noeigen,calcall)
8        0.416763000     -1.336451000     -0.208978000
6        1.497193000     -0.113742000      0.149606000
6       -0.772891000     -1.071748000      0.210613000
6       -1.509741000     -0.011936000     -0.327122000
6        0.829456000      1.060608000     -0.253868000
1        2.339023000     -0.475266000     -0.444938000
1        1.609073000     -0.346478000      1.210997000
6       -0.368126000      1.414823000      0.371361000
1       -0.923592000      2.282901000      0.026388000
1       -0.520920000      1.227340000      1.430860000
1        1.106186000      1.529032000     -1.191942000
1       -2.506791000      0.192973000      0.036038000
1       -1.388722000      0.264355000     -1.370246000
1       -1.103706000     -1.651275000      1.071122000

#p b97d3/def2SV/W06 opt=(ts,noeigen,calcall)
8       -0.556373000     -1.341873000     -0.246607000
6        1.267703000     -0.946693000      0.176479000
6       -1.313091000     -0.435583000      0.272443000
6       -1.504992000      0.814802000     -0.295637000
6        1.395538000      0.372483000     -0.314454000
1        1.717678000     -1.782296000     -0.375359000
1        1.166045000     -1.105900000      1.259763000
6        0.768640000      1.425447000      0.328791000
1        0.744341000      2.432184000     -0.112679000
1        0.518449000      1.360808000      1.397182000
1        1.705654000      0.503456000     -1.362984000
1       -2.163740000      1.551184000      0.190272000
1       -1.227963000      0.987609000     -1.343598000
1       -1.692271000     -0.594810000      1.314532000
```

Comment: That's true, it's exactly what you'd expect. 
However, because of the bonds breaking and forming at the TS, would you account for the BSSE when computing the activation barrier for the reaction?

Comment: I never really saw someone using BSSE correction, if it is not directly about it. From what I could see, the common way is to use bigger basis sets.